# Is there a program for vectorial house plans \ sketches?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

[image]

I'm trying to plan my new garden, and want to sketch it professionally - with dimensions of every element in it.

Is there an Ubuntu program for sketching house plans with vectorial elements, like those in the picture above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### SweetHome3D

I suggest [SweetHome3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/), it is in [the apt repos](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sweethome3d). Here is a screenshot, from its website:

[image: screenshot]

It is also [on Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.sweethome3d.Sweethome3d). After [installing it](https://www.flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) you can install SH3D to your user with

```
flatpak --user install flathub com.sweethome3d.Sweethome3d
```

Answer (score 12):

There is a program called [Librecad](http://packages.ubuntu.com/librecad) [image: Install librecad] that may be what you are looking for.

[image: LibreCad Screenshot]

To install LibreCad click the icon above or copy and paste the following command into Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install librecad
```

Then Press Enter, enter your password when prompted.

Comment: I removed my identical one :)